# shorten length string ignore Non-Space Characters like arabic diacritic Character without cutting words

Tags: javascript, regex, string, count, short

lets say i have this string that contain Non-Space Characters:

```
thisHُ is a long string I cant display
```

as you can see this "Hُ " contain  Non-Space Characters now i want to short the string so i did this:

```
  var text = "thisHُ is a long string I cant display"
  text =text.replace(/^((.){0,9})(.*)/gm, "$1"); 
  console.log(text);
```

this will give:

```
thisHُ is
```

but i don't want to count the Non-Space Characters i want to shorten the string with ignoring  "counting" Non-Space Characters also i want to shorten string without cutting the words boundary.

Comment: Try `text.replace(/^((?:\P{M}\p{M}*){0,9}\S*).*/su, '$1')`. Or, `/^((?:[^\p{M}\s]\p{M}*){0,9}\S*).*/su`

Comment: what if string start with Non-Space Characters ? and what if string dose not have Non-Space Characters at all ?

Comment: This is not a problem since it use ``*`` wildcard which matches zero or more consecutive characters

Comment: OK thank you one more thing how to short the string not  the end but from start ?
i mean shorten On the contrary cut from start and keep the rest of string...

Comment: So, you need 1) `text.replace(/^(\p{M}*(?:\P{M}\p{M}*){0,9}\S*).*/su, '$1')` and 2) `text.replace(/^\p{M}*(?:\P{M}\p{M}*){0,9}\S*\s*/u, '')`, right?

Comment: yes yes  i need both thanks it worked

Comment: yes but the limitation for sec one i need non cutting string is counted by limited length  i mean for example :
"thisHُ is a long string I cant display"
keep for example 9 length character starting from end and remove the rest so the string be like this:
"cant display"

Comment: I am not sure I guessed it right before. I think now, you need 1) `s.match(/^(?:\s*\S){1,9}/)[0]` and 2) `s.match(/\S*(?:\S\s*){1,9}$/)[0]`

Comment: thank you so much for your patience it working now thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

- `s.match(/^(?:\s*\S){1,9}\S*/)[0]`
- `s.match(/\S*(?:\S\s*){1,9}$/)[0]`

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/yOavgJ/2) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/yOavgJ/3).

The `^(?:\s*\S){1,9}\S*` regex matches one to nine occurrences of 0+ whitespaces followed with a single non-whitespace char at the start of string and then any 0+ non-whitespace chars.

The `\S*(?:\S\s*){1,9}$` regex will match 0+ non-whitespace chars and then one to nine occurrences of a single non-whitespace char followed with 0+ whitespaces at the end of string.

JavaScript demo:

```js
const text = "thisHُ is a long string I cant display";
const startMatch = text.match(/^(?:\s*\S){1,9}\S*/);
const endMatch = text.match(/\S*(?:\S\s*){1,9}$/);
if (startMatch) console.log(`Match at start: ${startMatch[0]}`);
if (endMatch) console.log(`Match at end: ${endMatch[0]}`);
```